# Помогите составить регулярку на питоне, задача тривиальная

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Собственно есть переменная, значение которой меняется в каждом проходе цикла, допустим называется переменная word, у нее есть какое-то текстовое значение 'worD' (которое меняется), необходимо найти есть ли совпадения значения этой переменной в исходном тексте, есть всего два условия:

1. Совпадения должно находить вне зависимости от регистра любой из букв в значении(даже если в тексте они другие).
2. В начале и конце этого совпадения может быть любой другой символ.

Comment: "любой другой символ" Вы имеете ввиду находится не в начале или в конце строки или является частю слова (любой символ кроме пробельных)? Или точнее так. любой другой смвол может быть или должен быть?

Comment: вообще любой может в том числе и пробел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re
text = """adworDis kill the word appliesworD
adworDis kill the wOrd appliesword"""

print(
    re.findall(r'word', text, flags=re.I)
)
# ['worD', 'word', 'worD', 'worD', 'wOrd', 'word']
```

Comment: re.findall(r'word', text, flags=re.I) как мне в это выражение вставить, точнее где r'word' вставить название переменной так значение постоянно меняется, тут я так понимаю частный случай?

Comment: Мне просто нужно проверить есть или нет хоть одно совпадение я делаю re.search(word, text, flags=re.I) но почему то глухо, не работает аналогично re.findall.

Comment: `bool(re.findall(r'word', text, flags=re.I))` ну а вооще `bool(re.search(r'word', text, flags=re.I))`, `len(re.findall(r'word', text, flags=re.I)) != 0`